# .dat* filename handling in .Net and Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

While troubleshooting a performance problem, I came across an issue in Windows 8 which relates to file names containing .dat (e.g. file.dat, file.data.txt).

I found that it takes over 6x as long to create them as any file with any other extension.

The same issue occurs in windows explorer where it takes significantly longer when copying folders containing .dat* files.

I have created some sample code to illustrate the issue.

```
internal class DatExtnIssue
{
    internal static void Run()
    {
        CreateFiles("txt");
        CreateFiles("dat");
        CreateFiles("dat2");
        CreateFiles("doc");
    }

    internal static void CreateFiles(string extension)
    {
        var folder = Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\FileTests", extension);
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var n = 0; n < 500; n++)
        {
            var fileName = Path.Combine(folder, string.Format("File-{0:0000}.{1}", n, extension));
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                // Left empty to show the problem is due to creation alone
                // Same issue occurs regardless of writing, closing or flushing
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(".{0} = {1,6:0.000}secs", extension, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000.0);
    }

}
```

Results from creating 500 files with the following extensions

```
.txt  =  0.847secs
.dat  =  5.200secs
.dat2 =  5.493secs
.doc  =  0.806secs
```

I got similar results using:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{ }
```

and:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, "a");
```

This caused a problem as I had a batch application which was taking far too long to run. I finally tracked it down to this.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening? Is this by design? I hope not, as it could cause problems for high-volume application creating .dat files.

It could be something on my PC but I have checked the windows registry and found no unusual extension settings.

Comment: Have you checked anti-virus?  That may have a special rule for .dat

Comment: I checked anti-virus. I even disabled it but that made no difference.

Comment: To clarify, it does not affect .dat as extension only, I get the same issue if .dat is anywhere in the filename (for example file.datacenter.txt).

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, try a kludge:

Write all files out as .txt and then rename *.txt to .dat.  Maybe it will be faster :)

Comment: Same problem occurs with an added overhead due to renaming. Where I have name control, I am simply avoiding .dat* now. However, I am concerned that some other standard extensions may be affected.